# Raspberry pi touchscreen

Tags: raspberry-pi, touchscreen, raspbian

I have some touchscreen(s) at home and I want to get one working on my raspberry pi. But the problem is that I must recompile the kernel. I followed this tutorial (http://engineering-diy.blogspot.be/2013/02/raspberry-pi-raspbian-xbmc-and-egalax-7.html?m=1). 
I downloaded the kernel but I don't know how to find the `lib` folder on my SD card. If I place the kernel in the `lib` folder, the raspberry pi boots up but the mouse and the keyboard  freezes.

Where can I find the `/lib` folder of my rpi?

Comment: "boot ip nut the mouse andere keyboard is freezed" is hilarious, but impossible to understand what it means. Google translate? That never goes well.

Comment: Try http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ for non software-related rPi questions.

Comment: Sorry. When i boot up my raspberry pi andere the gui starts ip. I cannot use the mouse ore the keyboard. I olso cannot log in whit ssh.

Answer (score 1):

To awnser your question: The lib folder is at the root of your SD card. You say you can't find it but you did place the kernel image in it? Seems contradicting :)

I wanted to install the same touschscreen.
Use this website:
http://engineering-diy.blogspot.nl/2013/01/adding-7inch-display-with-touchscreen.html

The following files should be replaced:
- `kernel.img`
- `kernel7.img`
- `bootcode.bin`
- `/lib/firemwire`
- `/lib/modules`
- `/opt/vc`

When you put your SD card in your computer you should see the boot partition and the big partition (of 2+gb depends on your sd card).

In the boot partition you place: the `kernel`, `kernel7.img` and `bootcode.bin`
In the big partition you should see the folders:
- `bin`
- `boot`
- `dev`
- `etc`
- `home`
- `lib`
and more..

Here you navigate to /lib and here you place the firmware and modules.
In /opt you place the vc folder.

Good luck!

---

**Edit**
I created a repos where you can find all files you need: [de-rpi2](https://github.com/hawkerboy7/de-rpi2)